# how to split string in Snowflake by single backslash

Tags: replace, split, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, backslash

have a problem I can't solve directly using Snowflake docs:

I have a strings like 'abc\def'

need to split it to 'abc', 'def'

tried:
split_to_table('abc\def', '\\') - error

strtok_to_array('abc\def', '\\') ==> [
"abcdef"
]

also, I've tried to replace it to better delimiter prior the split

replace('abc\cde','\\','_another_symbol_'); ==> abccde
REGEXP_REPLACE('abc\cde','$$\$$','_another_symbol_') ==> *abccde_another_symbol*

but it doesn't work

any idea how to solve that?

Comment: Is `abc\def` a value from the table or just a literal string you're playing with?. If it was properly escaped, it must have been loaded in as `abc\\def`, which would work with `select  split_part('abc\\def','\\',1)`

Comment: it's a field value we transferred from another source to Snowflake

Comment: When you run a select on the snowflake table  do you see `abc\def` or `abcdef`?

Comment: If you  are looking for only one '\' and you want to split into 2 words then you can try this.      select 'abc/def',SUBSTR( 'abc/def',1, regexp_instr(  'abc/def', '/')-1 ) first_w,
SUBSTR( 'abc/def', regexp_instr(  'abc/def', '/')+1 ) secound_w  from dual ;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just use SPLIT it will split the values into an array which you can then process however you want e.g.

```
with dataset as (
     select $1 as col1 from
     (values
     ('abc\\def'),
     ('ghi\\jkl'))
 )
 select col1, split(col1,'\\')
 from dataset
```

| COL1 | SPLIT(COL1,'\') |
| --- | --- |
| abc\def | [ "abc", "def" ] |
| ghi\jkl | [ "ghi", "jkl" ] |

Comment: thank you, it really stores the value in a proper splittable format
but I've tried that debug on the wrong string
thank you!